# Control audio balance in Android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, volume

I'm looking for a way to control the balance (left/right) of an audio stream in Android.
More specifically, I want to control the balance of the audio stream for music playback (`AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`).

I know I could control the balance of audio by using the MediaPlayer or SoundPool, but I don't want to build a music playback application myself. I simply want to control the balance of music played back by another app (like the default audio player).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I also had a look at the android.media.audiofx package, but it's unclear to me whether a custom implemented AudioEffect could be a solution for my problem. It would at least require some way to link an effect to a stream, which is not possible as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hey @gummbahla, I think there are no left/right speakers in Android. There is only one single output device!